# nested SQL query referencing a single table is running into infinite loop

Tags: sql, infinite-loop, subquery

This is how my query is structured but the loop is running infinite times. I am referencing a single table twice.

```
with XYZ AS(SELECT a, number, c, d, 1 as level
             FROM table
             WHERE condition = 99999

           UNION ALL 

             SELECT a, number, c, d, level + 1 as level
             FROM table b 

           JOIN  
             XYZ AS variable
             ON (variable.num = b.number)
             WHERE b.condition = 99999)

          SELECT *
          FROM XYZ
          ORDER BY level
```

this is the expected output

| a | number | c | d | level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mno | 100 | abc@gmail.com | CEO | 1 |
| pqr | 101 | bac@gmail.com | executive | 2 |
| qrs | 102 | cab@gmail.com | executive | 2 |
| stu | 103 | def@gmail.com | manager | 3 |

Comment: What are you trying to do with this recursive CTE? What is the expected condition for it to exit recursion?

Comment: I am  using this recursive CTE to query hierarchical org structure.

Comment: so the first query let's say returns the CEO of an organisation. the second query should return all the employees of the org and their hierarchy is in +1 in relation to that of the CEO and when it reads the list of all employees in the table (which is about 80000 records) it should exit the recursion.

Comment: You've obfuscated the query so much difficult to tell what is going on. The recursive branch references `variable.num` where `num` is supposed to be a column from `XYZ` but it has no such column in the anchor branch. If you are joining on `number = number` then unsurprising that it loops infinitely. you would normally be joining parentId to ChildId

Comment: SELECT a, number, c, d, 1 as level
             FROM table
             WHERE condition = 99999

           UNION ALL 

             SELECT a, number, c, d, level + 1 as level
             FROM table b

let's say i try only portion of the query without the recursive element, it says, level is an invalid column. How do i get that to work, because all i am doing is adding +1 to that of the first employees (who is the CEO) for all subsequent employees.

Answer (score -1):

I might be miss understanding you, are you just trying to add a column called With all the data called level 2?

if so this should work
ALTER TABLE MYTABLE ADD MYNEWCOLUMN VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT 'level2'